# how to print the value of array?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

```
let x = {a:1,b:2};
const xarr = [];
for(let i in x){
    xarr.push(i); 
    console.log(i);
}

//output is a, b but I want output 1 and 2.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673527/get-value-out-of-an-object-using-a-for-in-loop-in-javascript#20673539

Comment: Also, `x` is not an array, it is an object. `i` is the property of the object. You can access the values using `x[i]` - as shown in linked duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you need to use  **x[i] not i** for printing

```js
   let x = {a:1,b:2};
    const xarr = [];
    for(let i in x){
             console.log(x[i]);

     xarr.push(x[i]); 
    }
    
         console.log(xarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`Object.values(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) .Is Return with array format

```js
let x = {a:1,b:2};
var res =Object.values(x);
console.log(res.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop in javascript will iterate over the keys of an object, if you want the values you will have to fetch then om the object using that key.

```js
let x = {a:1,b:2};
const xarr = [];
for(let i in x){
 xarr.push(x[i]); 
 console.log(x[i]);
}
```